# I bought an open-box laptop. Should I reset Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, malware, spyware

Some time ago I bought a cheap laptop, essentially a netbook, to ensure that if my main laptop stopped working, I would have a laptop to work on while my main laptop was being repaired.

The box for the netbook had already been opened, i.e., the seal had been broken. However, it was the last remaining laptop of that model in the store and the deal was really good, so I bought it. Visually, the laptop looked entirely new, with no signs of use whatsoever. The consultant at the store was unable to explain why the box had been opened. But it was a really big electronics store, and the consultant may have simply not known.

When I came home, I turned the netbook on, and it went through the usual steps you have to go through when you turn on a new Windows laptop. That is, I was prompted to choose the language, region, come up with a username, etc.

However, after the setup process was completed, I looked in the Windows logs and saw some prior activity there. The prior activity was on two days, separated by about a week, about a month prior to the date on which I bought the laptop. Here's an example of a log entry from that prior activity: `"Error while updating Windows Defender status to SECURITY_PRODUICT_STATE_ON."`

I guess someone purchased the netbook online, opened the box, turned the netbook on, didn't like it, and returned it to the store,
and the staff rolled back the setup process or reset the Windows. But I don't know what actually happened.

My concern is that since I was able to see the old logs, the netbook might theoretically have some spyware installed by the people who had access to the netbook before I bought it. I'd prefer a surely clean system because I may use this netbook for banking and cryptocurrency operations.

So, my first instinct was to try to entirely reset the Windows myself, choosing the option of not keeping any personal files, but the problem is that the netbook is so weak (physical memory 4GB, hard drive 64 Gb) that I'm unsure that resetting Windows will go smoothly. I've seen one anecdotal message on the Internet saying that resetting Windows on a netbook of this particular model failed and that the attempt to reset Windows rendered the netbook a useless brick.

**My question:** Based on the fact that I was prompted to choose the language, region, etc. (when I turned the netbook on for the first time after I bought it), is it safe to say that the system is clean and free of any possible spyware? Or is there any way to find it out by looking somewhere in the system? Or does the presence of old logs indicate that the only way to guarantee a clean system is to reset Windows?

Netbook: Acer Aspire 1 A114 series; Model No.: N20Q1; System: Windows 10 Home in S mode

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you entered the Out of Box Experience (OOBE) means that all
traces were removed of the previous user (if there was one).
It does not mean that such a user did not install some software
on the computer.

If you would rather avoid resetting Windows, you could still do this:

- Examine Programs and Features to see if some software was installed
  after Windows which you don't need
- Run antivirus deep scans to check that the previous user has not
  managed to get the computer infected.

As this computer is only intended to serve as a backup, I think that
these measures are enough.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that:

> I'd prefer a surely clean system because I may use this netbook for banking and cryptocurrency operations.

The only way to *truly* do this is to reflash the BIOS and reinstall the OS.

It's trivially easy for a bad person to install malware in the non-volatile storage (e.g. SSD or HDD) of a device and then return it.  Likely?  **Probably not.**  Trivial?  **Yes.**  Does it happen?  **Yes.**

On many devices, it's also trivially easy for a bad person to do the same to the BIOS.

Examining `Programs and Features` in Windows will not detect any such malware.

Running antivirus deep scans could possibly detect such malware, but it depends on whether the potential malware installed on the device matches a signature of malware that had been previously identified by the antivirus author at the time the AV (antivirus) signatures were last updated.  AV heuristics could also possibly detect malware, but no heuristic is perfect.

If the AV tool detects possible malware, you also run the risk of spending hours (or days) of your time trying to determine if the items the AV detected are actual malware or are false positives.  Unless you are an experienced assembly language programmer, you will not have a way to do this reliably.  (And even for us experienced assembly language programmers, it's a very time consuming and tedious task.)